# Expressing data constraints in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm writing up a scheduling application for my wife, and I ran into the following question.

I have a schema that can be described in ActiveRecord terms as such:

- Each **resource** has and belongs to many *event*s
- Each **event** has and belongs to many *resource*s, and has many *timespan*s
- Each **timespan** belongs to an *event*, and has three attributes: *day*, *start-time*, and *end-time*.

I want to put the following constraints on my data:

```
    A. For each timespan, timespan.start-time ≤ timespan.end-time
    B. For each event, for each t_a, t_b ∈ TIMESPANS(event), 
       either t_a = t_b
           or t_a.day ≠ t_b.day
           or t_a.end-time ≤ t_b.start-time
           or t_a.start-time ≥ t_b.end-time
    C. For each resource, for each e_a, e_b ∈ EVENTS(resource),
       either e_a = e_b
           or for each t_a ∈ TIMESPANS(e_a) and t_b ∈ TIMESPANS(e_b),
              either t_a.day ≠ t_b.day
                  or t_a.end-time ≤ t_b.start-time
                  or t_a.start-time ≥ t_b.end-time
```

(A) makes sure timespans are well-formed, (B) makes sure events don't self-conflict, and (C) makes sure resources aren't over-scheduled.

Currently I'm enforcing these constraints at the application layer, but, in the interest of self-learning, I was wondering if I can put these constraints in the database layer.

Is there any way I can express these constraints in SQL?

**EDIT:**
So I found that what I wanted was SQL's `CREATE ASSERTION` statement (at least, for the ones that couldn't be covered by a simple `CHECK`), but it doesn't seem like any RDBMS that supports it ([at least, as of 2005](http://www.dbmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/databases/1991/Which-RDBMS-supports-the-CREATE-ASSERTION-statement))

Comment: You're scheduling your wife? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is easily expressed in a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on your timespan table, since each row can check itself for consistency without checking any other rows.

B and C are more complex and would require a reading information out of other tables.  In this case (at least in SQL Server), one could use a user-defined function (passing it the values from the current row) to check against the other tables or you could use a `TRIGGER` which would check the other tables.

NB: When writing such a trigger, remember that a trigger fires once for a SQL statement.  If that statement `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s multiple rows, the `INSERTED` table will contain multiple rows, which should all be checked to match your domain constraints using an appropriate technique, like a `JOIN`.

BTW: Joe Celko had a [good article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/constraint-yourself!/) recently on constraints.